# Why Performance drop for GetDetailsOf Owner?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

Using GetDetailsOf I get two properties for files in a Folder (actually multiple folders).
These two properties are Date/Time and Owner.
Date/Time is really fast (~1 second); However, Owner takes a really long time (~10 minutes).

Is this usual behaviour? If so, why is that?

EDIT: Running the code on a folder locally stored cuts the time down to fractions of a second (My folders aren't locally stored though). Using GetSecurityDescriptor cuts the time in half (which is great!), but I still don't see why getting the Owner of the file takes so much longer then getting the created date/time of the same file.

Get Created Date/Time:

```
t = Timer
For Ctr2 = 2 To LastRow2
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("J:\" & ws4.Cells(Ctr2, 1) & "\") 'Path should always contain a '\' at end
    For Each SFile In oDir.Items
        If DateValue(oDir.GetDetailsOf(SFile, 4)) > Time Then
            Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(SFile, 0)
        End If
    Next
Next
Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 7)
```

Get Owner:

```
   t2 = Timer
    For Ctr2 = 2 To LastRow2
    Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("J:\" & ws4.Cells(Ctr2, 1) & "\") 'Path should always contain a '\' at end
        For Each SFile In oDir.Items
            Owner = oDir.GetDetailsOf(SFile, 10)
            Debug.Print Owner
        Next
        Owner = ""
    Next
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t2, 7)
```

Comment: When you look up the file owner through Windows Explorer, is that slow, too?

Comment: Yes - you could have some sort of connection issue with the domain controller which would make resolving SSIDs slow, if that was the case, then showing the security settings/owner settings in the Explorer would be slow, too.

Comment: Also, try your code on a different PC. And on local files. And other network drives.

Comment: Running against the Folder on local drive produced vastly improved results. Down to fraction of a second per folder for Owner (which is expected)

Comment: Could be any combination of: Your network drive is slow. / The ACLs on the files in question is corrupt for some reason. / You have domain controller communication issues. / The `GetDetailsOf` call itself is inefficient for your situation. Hard to say. I would suggest using a different method to get the file Owner. You could try [ADSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadssecurityutility): `Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")` and then `Set fileSec = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(SFile, 1, 1)` and then `MsgBox(fileSec.owner)`

Comment: If that works, you can add the ADSI type library ("Active DS Type Library") as a reference in your VBA project ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/setting-up-visual-basic-for-adsi-development)). This way early binding (`Dim secUtil As New IADsSecurityUtility`) should start to work, which will give you get IntelliSense for these objects in the VBA IDE.

Comment: I don't know exactly, use the Object Browser (F2) to figure out the correct names. I don't have VBA handy right now. But for trying out the idea, `CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I did get it working - I needed to add a filepath to SFile in GetSecurityDescriptor(SFile, 1, 1). Folder contains two file types (TIF,PDF) that I had to specify.
I used poor programming and used On Error Resume Next and did a line with TIF and the same line again for PDF. 
It did make a noticeable performance increase, but still really slow (~1sec per file looked at instead of a fraction of a second for multiple files).

Comment: I guess then you should concentrate on investigating performance issues on the shared drive, issues with the ACLs themselves, and potentially network performance issues between your machine and the domain. Since you've confirmed that accessing local files is quick, it can't be VBA's fault, and network drives are not slow by default. So it must be something with this particular drive, the files on that drive, or some other circumstantial factor.

Comment: True, but why does getting the created time of the file lightning fast while getting owner is so slow for same file same folder. I'm using the same command - still file a file property. If you want to delete some comments and repost the ADsSecurityUtility as a performance boost alternate I can upvote. It helped cut time in half.

Comment: Because the file owner is an SID that needs to be retrieved along with the file's ACL, which is a complex data strcuture, and the SIDs must be resolved into user names with the help of a domain controller. It's not a field on the file with a string `"domain\user"`, or a date - the process is much more complex than that. I don't keep pointing at network issues and/or ACL issues for no reason.

Comment: Thanks!
Sorry I should have specified I was more so curious as to the difference between handling Owner compared to Date/time. (not so much any potential network or SIDs issues)

Comment: Well, now you know. :)